# Laravel 4 mews captcha no error, but not showing picture

Tags: php, laravel-4, captcha

I have a problem with mews captcha package. I have an application on Laravel 4.2. In this application there is a feedback form. I am using mews captcha package in it. But captcha picture not showing. I have enabled gd library.
this is my config/app.php:

providers

```
'Mews\Captcha\CaptchaServiceProvider'
```

alias:

```
'Captcha'         => 'Mews\Captcha\Facades\Captcha',
```

and html where I am calling captcha:

```
<span class="input-group-addon">{{ HTML::image(Captcha::img()) }}</span>
```

Can you help me?

**EDIT**

html in brouser:

[image: captcha]

And this is, if I open captcha url in brouser:

[image]

**EDIT2**

code inspector:

[image]

**EDIT3**:

when I tried to save it in jpeg or jpg format, and opened it

[image]

Comment: Please post the html you see in the browser as a result. It's also worth checking php/laravel logs for anything interesting

Comment: Ivan, I have edited the post

Comment: thanks, the captcha url content looks like a jpeg image. I was asking about the html code around `input-group-addon` in your web browser (the thing which you observe after doing right mouse click and `View Page Source` or equivalent in your browser.

Comment: Here you are!!!

Comment: Thanks. So for some reason doesn't render the image. Either the problem is with the image generated or the browser. Could you please 1) post the screenshot of your browser's Console 2) go to the captcha image url, save it as a .jpg file and try if it can be open by an image viewer

Comment: I have saved as jpg, jpeg, but image wasn't genereated, there was an error

Comment: I have tested it in 3 browser, but no result

Comment: " there was an error" --> post the error here

Comment: This is when I open saved image

Comment: Please try [jpeginfo](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/46919/is-there-a-tool-to-check-the-file-integrity-of-a-series-of-images) to see what's wrong with the image